# Nightmarejs "Unexpected token ..."

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, nightmare

When loading a page with Nightmare I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

When it parses the following

```
const r={domain:S.cookieDomain,expires:60,...n};
```

This looks like standard array syntax for ES6. I'm using Nodejs 11.9.0. Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: What is `...`? If those are actual periods then that's what's wrong. Remove the `...n` element and it should work.

Comment: It's called a spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Can it parse successfully without the spread operator?

Comment: It seems to be a Electron issue https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/1202

Comment: @Viggo In my regular browser, yes. The issue is in Nightmarejs

Comment: @cbaconnier thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since as @cbaconnier points out in the comments the issue is with Electron, upon which NightmareJS depends, I ended up resolving this by switching to Puppeteer. The syntax is very similar to Nightmare and I did not have the freedom to remove the problematic script or change its use of the spread operator.